# sonarlint failed to analyze javascript code

Tags: node.js, sonarlint

sonarlint version: 6 ,
sonarqube version 9.2 ,
nodejs 16  and
configuration :
Node.js path is C:\programFile\nodejs but again plaese configure nodejs path in sonarlint setting.

Comment: What is the error ??

Answer (score 7):

I solved it by setting the path to `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe` on Sonar lint configuration.

Comment: Hello, could you please specify where does this path should be configured in VSCode?

Comment: @jmonloop on vsc settings search for `sonarlint.pathToNodeExecutable`

Comment: Same on linux. I am using nvm to install node. Setting it to /home/myname/.nvm/versions/node/v21.2.0/bin/node solved it for me